# Implementation of a Django powered service with browser and mobile app clients?

Tags: android, python, django, model-view-controller, django-rest-framework

I'm creating a django powered service which would have browser and mobile app clients.

I understand the flow and technical architecture for the browser flow.
Browser requests a page from the server and Django serves it **(data + template = page).**

But in case of mobile clients, they only need **data** (**json**). In this case how should I serve just the data. 
I did a research and I got to know that I can use **django-rest-framework** to create apis to serve just the data but I'm still not clear how can I serve requests specific to different clients (page or just the data).

Comment: Why do you need to serve different responses on the same paths? Why not use a specific path for mobile data, or at least a parameter in the query string?

Comment: to further @DanielRoseman comment; many people choose to do m.mysite.com for the mobile, and www.mysite.com for web (essentially setup two ways to access your site) where m.mysite.com will send JSON data

Comment: by mobile app I mean Android/iOS clients which would be requesting JSON data from the server. I understand that in case of mobile browsers I can server mobile specific templates. But I'm not able to understand how can serve just JSON data in case client is an android/iOS app.